# Rewrite subdomain.domain.com to domain.com/subdomain without redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I've read plenty of Stackoverflows but I seem to be missing something.

I have a PHP application running on https://subdomain.example.com/page/x but for SEO reasons I want people/bots to see https://example.com/subdomain/page/x.

I can rewrite the URL by using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/subdomain/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This rewrite results in: `https://example.com/subdomain/page/x`, but I keep recieving a 404 error since the "main" domain doesn't know the path `/subdomain/page/x` of course.

What I want is to have the URL `https://example.com/subdomain/page/x` but run it on `https://subdomain.example.com/` in the background since this is the place where the PHP application is running.

Is this possible? How should I do this?

Comment: What is the underlying file structure? Where does the subdomain point to in relation to the domain apex? Are they on the same file system or unrelated?

Comment: @MrWhite The two are unrelated: on a different server and different technology running.

Comment: But still Apache? Do you have access to the server config at the domain apex?

Comment: @MrWhite Not necessarily Apache. There will always be access to the server of "example.com" if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no strong SEO reason not to use subdomains.  See [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)  I recommend using subdirectories most of the time but subdomains when they are warranted.

One place where subdomains are warranted is when your content is hosted on a separate server in a separate hosting location. While it is technically possible to serve the content from a subdirectory from the separate server, that comes with its own set of SEO problems:

1. It will be slow.
2. It will introduce duplicate content.

From a technical standpoint, you would need to use a reverse proxy to on your `example.com` webserver to fetch content for the `/subdomain/` subdirectory from `subdomain.example.com`.  The code for doing so in the `.htaccess` file of `example.com` would be something like:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*)$ https://subdomain.example.com/$1 [P]
```

The `[P]` flag means "reverse proxy" which will cause the server to fetch the content from the remote subdomain.  This will necessarily make it slower for users.  So much so that it would be better for SEO to use a subdomain.

For this to work you would also need to leave the subdomain up and running  and serving content for the main server to fetch.  This causes duplicate content. You could solve this issue by implementing canonical tags pointing to the subdirectory.

This requires several Apache modules to be available.  On my Debian based system I needed to run `sudo a2enmod ssl proxy rewrite proxy_connect proxy_http` and `sudo service apache2 reload`.  I also had to add `SSLProxyEngine on` in my `<VirtualHost>` directive for the site I wanted to use this on.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I understand what' you're saying concerning SEO and will look into it. 
I tried your RewriteRule (in the `.htaccess` of `example.com`) but it just redirects me to the URL `https:/subdomain.example.com/page/x`. Which is not my intention since I want the URL `https://example.com/subdomain/page/x`.

Comment: That rule is supposed to proxy it and keep the URL.  If it is redirecting, something is wrong.

Comment: Any idea what could be wrong? Could it be that the `domain.com` should be dynamic instead of hardcoded?

Comment: How are you testing? Are you using `curl --head https://example.com/subdomain/page/x` on the command line?  Alternately, are you clearing your browser cache between each test?  The redirects you are seeing could be coming from browser cache rather than from your server.

Comment: If you have just one subdomain you want to proxy, hard coding it is fine.  I'd only recommend dynamic if you have a bunch of them and a pattern for their URLs.

Comment: You also have to enable `mod_proxy` on your server to be able to use a rule like that.

Comment: Mod_proxy is enabled on the server. I delete browser cache every test. Everything seems to be set-up as defined. However the desired URL `https://example.com/subdomain/page/x`still redirects to `https://subdomain.example.com/page/x`

Comment: Do you have any other rules that could be causing the redirect?  If you comment out the proxy rule, do you get a 404 error? Are there any helpful messages in your server's `error_log`?

Comment: I put the literal rule on my server and I get `Proxy Error -- The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request. Reason: DNS lookup failure for: subdomain.example.com`, definitely not a redirect.

Comment: The only rule in the `.htaccess` is the one you provided. I just checked the `error_log` and nothing appears. The only thing I noticed is that there is a 301 redirect to the subdomain page.

Comment: I tested this rule out on my server, and it works fine.  I added the required Apache modules to the answer as well as a directive to enable ssl proxy.   It sounds like this may already be set up on your server.

Comment: The only other thing I can think to check for you would be that your subdomain itself isn't still redirecting.  If you try to proxy to a site that is redirecting you will just end up serving the redirect from the proxy.